# fixed vector in markov chain

Tags: statistics

following p is markov chain transition matrix.

$3\times3$

$$p = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1/2&            0&              1/2\\     
 2/3&           1/3&            0\\       
 0&              2/3&            1/3  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would like to know fixed vector $w=wP$ and try to show whether it is
reversible or not.

To find this, I tried

> $$
> p^2 = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>        1/4&            1/3&            5/12\\    
>        5/9&            1/9&            1/3\\      
>        4/9&            4/9&            1/9    
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

However, it seems there is no fixed number in the $p^3$ and $p^4 \dots p^n$ .  how can I find it?

Comment: Obviously not reversible since some p(i,j) are zero while p(j,i) is not. // Did you get something from the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for $w$ given the system of equations $w (P-I) = \mathbf{0}$ together with the additional constraint that $\sum w_i =1$.

Answer: (0.4, 0.3, 0.3)

Since your Markov chain is ergodic (since it is irreducible and aperiodic), the stationary distribution is unique, and the only distribution that can be checked for reversibility. It remains only to check whether $w_i P_{ij} = w_j P_{ji}$ for all pairs $i,j$.

Answer (score 0):

We would like to find $w$ such that
$$
wP = w
$$
This is the same as finding a $w$ such that
$$
wP - wI = \pmatrix{0&0&0}
$$
where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.  The above becomes
$$
w(P - I) = \pmatrix{0&0&0}\\
(P-I)^Tw^T = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}
$$
That is, our $w$ can be found by finding the kernel of the matrix
$$
(P-I)^T =
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1/2&            2/3&              0\\     
 0&           -2/3&            2/3\\       
 1/2&              0&            -2/3  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you solve this problem?